# find object id when key value in nested array has given string

Tags: json, jq

Input json is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00001",
    "profile": {
      "extensions": [
        {
          "name": "/somepath1...../AAAAAA"
        },
        {
          "name": "/somepath2...../xxxxxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "00002",
    "profile": {
      "extensions": [
        {
          "name": "/somepath1...../zzzzzz"
        },
        {
          "name": "/somepath2...../BBBBBB"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "00003",
    "profile": {
      "extensions": [
        {
          "name": "/somepath1...../yyyyyy"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "00004",
    "profile": {
      "extensions": []
    }
  }
]
```

I need to find id of object having .profile.extensions[].name having values containing string AAAAAA or BBBBBB.

Expected output for above json example would be:

```
00001 AAAAAA 
00002 BBBBBB
```

Because in the first one the is AAAAAA and in second BBBBBB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this filter pattern, which iterates over the array elements `.[]`, filters for matching items using `select` and outputs the field `id` as raw text due to the `-r` flag.

```sh
jq -r '.[] | select( … ).id'
```

What the expression within your `select` filter should be, depends on how you define "having values containing [a] string".

If the search string has to match the last part of a slash-delimited list of substrings (as your sample data might suggest), you could split up the target string using `/` (or `split`), extract the `last` item and use `IN` to apply the test to a stream of search strings. ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0efQaHAK6r))

```
IN(.profile.extensions[].name / "/" | last; "AAAAAA", "BBBBBB")
```

If the slashes should not be considered specially (i.e. a search string could also contain slashes) and if a search string simply appearing at the end of the target string is a match, then you can use `endswith` to test it and `any` to prevent multiple matches for the same `id` if several `name`s within the same iterated object end with a given search string. ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ma-xC4HsSp))

```
[.profile.extensions[].name | endswith("AAAAAA", "BBBBBB")] | any
```

If, however, the search string is allowed to appear *anywhere* in the `name`, just change `endswith` to `contains`. ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_PiiwglIiS))

```
[.profile.extensions[].name | contains("AAAAAA", "BBBBBB")] | any
```

---

Regarding your update which altered the output to include the matching search string, and your additional [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910624/find-object-id-when-key-value-in-nested-array-has-given-string/70910657?noredirect=1#comment125361655_70910657) stating that the target string is indeed a slash-separated list, the approach now is as follows:

In order to test *and* output the search string, i.e. to use *and* to reference it again, we need to store it in a variable (using `$s` here), which has to happen outside the `select` filter in order to have its scope reach until the output reference.

```sh
jq -r '.[] | ("AAAAAA", "BBBBBB") as $s
  | select(IN(.profile.extensions[].name / "/" | last; $s))
  | "\(.id) \($s)"
'
```

```
00001 AAAAAA
00002 BBBBBB
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-42b4uCl9U)

Comment: Thank you it works greate. I have added one update so expected output should also consist the extension name (without path), just all after last `/`...

Comment: @Chris Updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Just out of curiosity would it also be easy to label extensions and print label name instead? For example: `AAAAAA` is labeled `ext#1` and `BBBBBB` is `ext#2`? Of course I could process output with `sed` but maybe jq could do such replacament and give on output the two lines: one `00001 ext#1` and second `00002 etx#2`

Comment: @Chris jq is very powerful and can certainly do everything you have said. You just need to be specific on **what exactly** you want (ie. including edge cases etc.) and **where** it comes from (actually these were the main "complications" while answering your question because you didn't immediately specify, for instance, the slash-segmentation, or what you now mean by "label extensions"). But the latest solution should give you the necessary comfort to analogously grab whatever you want to display before the `select` filter, and then to include it in the string interpolation at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I used following `if` statement to achieve optional output I mentioned in my previoius comment: `.[] | ("AAAAAA", "BBBBBB") as $s | select(IN(.profile.extensions[].name / "/" | last; $s)) | "\(.id) \(if $s == "AAAAAA" then "ext#1" elif $s == "BBBBBB" then "ext#2" else . end)"`

Comment: @Chris Now I understand your "labels". You could simplify it by using an object with its keys being the search strings and its values being the labels: `.[] | ({"AAAAAA": "ext#1", "BBBBBB": "ext#2"} | to_entries[]) as $s | select(IN(.profile.extensions[].name / "/" | last; $s.key)) | "\(.id) \($s.value)"` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iPF13UxTzT)